# Unexpected Token Found in angular-errors.json File

Tags: unexpected-token

when I installed @angular-devkit/build-angular@17.0.10 for audit fix. I found this error - An unhandled exception occurred: Unexpected token '??=' See "/private/var/folders/tb/46cdx4ts0t7329ddw_rkhqgh0000gq/T/ng-mRBXOP/angular-errors.log" for further details.

i run npm audit fix command for critical package.but it doesn't.